# SQL Server 2012 Linked Server to MySQL Slow Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, performance, linked-server

I'm running SQL Server 2012 and have setup a Linked Server connection to a Linux MySQL instance via the latest MySQL ODBC drivers. I'm a bit disappointed by the time taken to return results of a fairly straightforward 'Select' query.

```
select * from OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'select * from mysqltable')
```

The table has approximately 150,000 rows and takes about 70 seconds to return the results to SSMS. Conversely if I query the table via a MySQL Client App (In this case Navicat Essentials, on the same machine as SQL Server) the query executes in about 1 second.

I know that Linked Servers and ODBC will be slower but I'm surprised by this performance hit, particularly with such a straight forward query.

I've tried both the Unicode and ANSI drivers and the performance is similar. The MySQL DB is UTF-8 CharSET and Coalition and the table is InnoDB. I've tried explicitly selecting columns rather than * also. Again no difference.

Has anyone experienced this before and got any tips for speeding up the performance or is this fairly normal?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the MySQL client app you are using only send back the first few rows and then retrieve additional rows as you scroll through the result set? I know that Toad did this when connecting to Oracle and would sometimes make you think a query ran much faster than it if all rows were returned together.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion. I'll check the logs for additional queries.

Comment: We use staging tables that we update on regular intervals (Once every 3 hours). Depending on how available and up to date you require your data to be, this might be a viable solution.

Answer (score 0):

In linked server 
I do not think there is a possibility to improve significantly 
But you can try through SSIS 
And use bulk insert.